# Is 3000 a reference to Iron Man in the comics?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics, iron-man, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*:

> Tony Stark has a daughter who keeps getting called "3000", or has several references to her as "3000".

Is this a reference to a specific character from the comics? Maybe they don't have a perfect comic counterpart, but is a reference to something else in the comics?

I should probably clarify since I must have written my question in a confusing way; I know how it was used in the movie. I knew that when I asked the question. That's not my question. My point is, a lot of comic book movies/TV shows make references to things from the comics. Great writers will even give a good reason to make that reference, instead of just stuffing it in there because.

A good example from DC TV is when Nora says, "It's a nickname my mother gave me because she said 'I always do everything in eXcesS.'" Good (or at least decent) reason to use XS. XS also has a double meaning in the sense that it's something from the comics too.

My question is: is 3000 a reference to something Tony Stark related in the *comics*, or did the writers just make it up for the movie?

Comment: His daughter is called Morgan. If they were going for a comics reference in her unit of love, she should have said she loved Tony two thousand, so that he could reply that he loves her two thousand and ninety-nine.

Comment: Why was this question voted down by 6 people. Seems like a valid question to me.

Comment: @LincolnMan because they have completely misunderstood the dialogue.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In light of the question update as to knowing what "3000" meant, but wondering whether that was a deliberate choice; not at all!

A recent interview reveals that the "3000" is something Robert Downey Jr's kids tell him, and makes no mention of a reference to comics. In fact the original script simply read "I love you tons".

> **Fandango: One of the most memorable lines in the film is Stark's "I love you, three thousand." Where did that come from?**
>
> **Christopher Markus:** Well much as we'd like to take credit for what is inevitably going to be one of the most memorable lines in MCU history, that is something that Robert and his children actually say to each other, and he brought it from real life onto the set.
>
> **Stephen McFeely:** The script was, "Love you tons. Love you tons." And now it's, "Love you tons. Love you 3000."
>
> <sub>[*The 'Avengers Endgame' Writers Break Down The Biggest Moments in The Movie*, Erik Davis for *Fandango*, May 3rd, 2019](https://www.fandango.com/movie-news/exclusive-interview-the-avengers-endgame-writers-break-down-the-biggest-moments-in-the-movie-spoilers-753736)</sub>

---

Former answer (before the question was updated):

It's not a nickname, it's a unitless measure of love.

Morgan tells Tony she "loves him three thousand"; that would be kid's words for levels of love she feels for him. Three thousand is quite a big figure for a 4/5 years old kid, so that's a *lot*.

Note that Tony says to Pepper something along the lines of,

> Not that it's a competition, but she loves me three thousand. You were at like, six or nine hundreds.

Meaning he's jokingly "comparing" his level with Pepper's.

And Tony says "I love you three thousand" back in

> His final message

Because he finds it cute and it got to him, so he's keeping the wording, just as a lot of parents adopt their kids' words to be closer to them.

Comment: I get that it was a joke/reference that paid off later. I'm just curious it it has any comic book meaning. Sometimes heroes have children in the comics that turn into other heroes eventually. Cassie Lang I think is an example. I'm just wondering is 3000 a code name from the comics for a hero that is, for instance, related to Tony Stark in the comics?

Comment: @Chipster doesn't ring a bell, but that doesn't mean there isn't (although additional Googling leads nothing obvious so far). Comics-wise Morgan Stark is Tony's cousin and usually not that much of a good guy. MCU-wise, I don't know what they'll do with her. Maybe they'll take a shot at Ironheart?

Comment: Just looked up Ironheart. That'd be a great way to take her. Still not seeing a connection to 3000, though. Maybe I'm just overthinking it. Anyway, thanks for your effort.

Comment: In Brazil, it was translated to something as "A thousand million". While it could be a dub error, I dont think it is a reference to anything. It is just a big number for a kid

Answer (score 0):

Tony said "I love you tons". A metric ton is 2000 lbs. Morgan was one-upping him by saying "I love you 3000". As far as I'm aware, there isn't any character named or codenamed '3000', but I'm not as up to date with current characters and events as I used to be.

Comment: I'm not sure what the relevance of the metric tonne is. Also, a Metric tonne is 2204.6... lbs, not 2000. Thirdly, why would Morgan know this fact?

Comment: Actually, a "tonne (metric)" is 1000kg or approximately 2205 lbs.  2000 lbs is a "short ton" or U.S. ton, as opposed to a "long ton" or imperial ton which is 2240 lbs.

Answer (score -8):

Towards the end when Thor joins the Guardians in the ship it implied that there might be another movie involving the Guardians. This may be a hint that Marvel will do a spin off of “*Guardians 3000*” that was a published comic in 2014 that talked about the future lives. So I believe x3000 is reference to another addition and future of MCU where they may take the stories next.

Comment: Whilst a nice theory the 3000 comment has no connection to the GotG in the film so this seems like quite a stretch.

Comment: Also FWIW there _is_ (still) going to be a GotG 3 so could be possible.

Comment: Look up the comic “guardians 3000” the storyline takes pace in the future so if a spin off movie is made maybe starks daughter or the boy from iron man 3(the teen during the scene at funeral)  will take part in the movie as they fight the bardoon

Comment: Guardians 3000 is a mcu comic book series that came out later

Answer (score -8):

[image]

Vance Astro(victory justice) could be war machine since cap America gave him the shield too so nitros theory could be on to something since something looks like it’s in the works

Comment: Aren't *you* "Nitro"? Or do you just share an email?